# Want to navigate to dial pad on clicking mobile number

Tags: objective-c, ios9.2

I want to navigate to default phone app on iphone on clicking the mobile number and on what object should i take to that number for clicking event .(objective c)

Comment: You just want to open the dialer (phone app) or also call an number?

Comment: want to see the number that I clicked on the dial pad

Comment: You can not get any information from other apps, unless the API allows it. The dialer is not accessable via any public API, you can only use the `tel:` scheme to dial a number.

Comment: what is  that tel: scheme ?

Comment: The `tel:` scheme allows to to call a number, like `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:"tel:12347162349"]]`